# Yeoman /dist/bower_components directory

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman, bower

I'm new to grunt, bower and yeoman world and I wonder why I have /dist/bower_components folder, when all the vendor javascripts are already joined in single file under *.vendor.js . Is it specific to generator-angular and can I prevent it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm also seeing this...and I'm also confused!  :)  I used yeoman to scaffold my project and have a bunch of bower-installed components.  When I run `grunt build`, it combines all the files into a vendor.js file, but then when I pushed my distribution folder live, I noticed that it was never referenced and the bower_components folder was used!  How do I set up grunt to use vendor.js instead?

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would not need `bower_components` in your `dist` folder if it has already been compiled into a `vendor.js` file.  Can you provide your grunt file?  sounds like there is a `copy` command that is doing more work than you need it to, by copying your `app/bower_components` into your dist folder on build.